# Searching for a counterexample to a decidable predicate

Tags: coq

It feels like the following Coq statement should be true constructively:

```
Require Import Decidable.

Lemma dec_search_nat_counterexample (P : nat -> Prop) (decH : forall i, decidable (P i))
  : (~ (forall i, P i)) -> exists i, ~ P i.
```

If there were an upper bound, I'd expect to be able to show something of the form "suppose that not every `i < N` satisfies `P i`. Then there is an `i < N` where `~ P i`". Indeed, you could actually write a function to find a minimal example by searching from zero.

Of course, there's not an upper bound for the original claim, but I feel like there should be an inductive argument to get there from the bounded version above. But I'm not clever enough to figure out how! Am I missing a clever trick? Or is there a fundamental reason that this cann't work, despite the well-orderedness of the natural numbers?

Comment: https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/what-axioms-do-i-need-to-search-the-naturals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reworked answer after Meven Lennon-Bertrand's comment**

This statement is equivalent to [Markov's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_principle) with `P` and `~P` exchanged. Since `P` is decidable we have `P <-> (~ ~ P)`, so that one can do this replacement.

This paper ([http://pauillac.inria.fr/~herbelin/articles/lics-Her10-markov.pdf](http://pauillac.inria.fr/%7Eherbelin/articles/lics-Her10-markov.pdf)) suggest that Markov's principle is not provable in Coq, since the author (one of the authors of Coq) suggests a new logic in this paper which allows to prove Markov's principle.

**Old answer:**

This is morally the "Limited Principle of Omniscience" - LPO (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_principle_of_omniscience). It requires classical axioms to prove it in Coq - or you assert itself as an axiom.

See e.g.:

```
Require Import Coquelicot.Markov.

Check LPO.

Print Assumptions LPO.
```

Afair there is no standard library version of it.

Comment: I thinks it’s more like [Markov’s principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_principle). LPO gives you a (constructive) or between the existence and the forall, while here you want to get past a negation, which is slightly weaker.

Comment: There is a proof that Markov's principle is not derivable in CIC by Pédrot and Tabareau in this paper: https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01840643 (Corollary 41).

Comment: The intuition for MP being unprovable: if you had `MP : forall P (dec : forall i, decidable (P i)), ~(forall i, P i) -> exists i, ~P i`, then the only sensible reduction rule for it is `MP P dec prf ~> match dec O with | or_introl yes => yes | or_introl no => let (i, prf) := MP (fun n => P (S n)) _etc _etc in _etc end` (where the `_etc`s are easy to fill in). Since `MP` is not (and cannot be) phrased as a `fix`point (which have certain guards against excessive unfolding), you can just keep expanding `MP` forever inside itself. Thus `MP` (in ordinary Coq) breaks strong normalization.